# [R]Coverting lists of numeric datas into dates in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

I was tidying some data with dirty dates(different styling), I tried with * lubridate * ,however I can only clean one list at a time.

**So is there anyways to convert all the date in several lists?**  All the lists that need to be transferred end with “T”, and, in real data I have more than 3lists, probably 30+.

The cleared data need to be “yyyy-mm”, no need of days.

[image: dirtydatatest]

```
    > dirtydatatest
# A tibble: 6 × 5
  city  name  hbpT       tbT        hepaT     
  <chr> <chr> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     
1 CityA Angel 2011-101   NA         20090909  
2 CityA Bob   2014-02-12 20090909   2011-127  
3 CityB Cathy 2011-10-12 2011-127   NA        
4 CityB Dean  NA         NA         2018.07.23
5 CityC Ellen 1992.10.1  2018.07.23 NA        
6 CityC Faye  2011-127   NA         NA
```

I used

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
 dirtydatatest = mutate(dirtydatatest,
tbT= ymd(tbT) ,.keep = c("all"),)
```

and then using *stringer* to change the “-”. But can only done in one list at a time.

And I tried to use

```
dirtydata2 %>%
select(dirtydata2, ends_with("t")) %>%
  mutate_all(ymd() ,.keep = c("all"),)
```

But I don’t think I’ve got it right ,as in **ymd()**, there should be something in it...

Thank you for your time and patience.

Answer (score 1):

First, I think `across` works well here to convert multiple columns to `Date`-class (and `mutate_all` and `mutate_at` have been superseded by it):

```r
dirtydataset %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with("T"), ymd))
# # A tibble: 6 x 5
#   city  name  hbpT       tbT        hepaT     
#   <chr> <chr> <date>     <date>     <date>    
# 1 CityA Angel 2011-10-01 NA         2009-09-09
# 2 CityA Bob   2014-02-12 2009-09-09 2011-12-07
# 3 CityB Cathy 2011-10-12 2011-12-07 NA        
# 4 CityB Dean  NA         NA         2018-07-23
# 5 CityC Ellen 1992-10-01 2018-07-23 NA        
# 6 CityC Faye  2011-12-07 NA         NA
```

As to your mention of *"need to be “yyyy-mm”, no need of days"*, then you can convert back to strings if you'd like, using `format`, though you lose some capabilities on it:

```r
dirtydataset %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with("T"), ~ format(ymd(.), format = "%Y-%m"))) 
# # A tibble: 6 x 5
#   city  name  hbpT    tbT     hepaT  
#   <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
# 1 CityA Angel 2011-10 NA      2009-09
# 2 CityA Bob   2014-02 2009-09 2011-12
# 3 CityB Cathy 2011-10 2011-12 NA     
# 4 CityB Dean  NA      NA      2018-07
# 5 CityC Ellen 1992-10 2018-07 NA     
# 6 CityC Faye  2011-12 NA      NA
```

---

Data

```r
dirtydataset <- structure(list(city = c("CityA", "CityA", "CityB", "CityB", "CityC", "CityC"), name = c("Angel", "Bob", "Cathy", "Dean", "Ellen", "Faye"), hbpT = c("2011-101", "2014-02-12", "2011-10-12", NA, "1992.10.1", "2011-127"), tbT = c(NA, "20090909", "2011-127", NA, "2018.07.23", NA), hepaT = c("20090909", "2011-127", NA, "2018.07.23", NA, NA)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `across` with `ymd`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
dirtydataset %>%
    mutate(across(ends_with("T"),  ~ymd(.x, truncated = 2)))
```

-output

```
 city  name       hbpT        tbT      hepaT
1 CityA Angel 2011-10-01       <NA> 2009-09-09
2 CityA   Bob 2014-02-12 2009-09-09 2011-12-07
3 CityB Cathy 2011-10-12 2011-12-07       <NA>
4 CityB  Dean       <NA>       <NA> 2018-07-23
5 CityC Ellen 1992-10-01 2018-07-23       <NA>
6 CityC  Faye 2011-12-07       <NA>       <NA>
```

With `mutate_at`, the syntax would be

```
dirtydataset %>%
    mutate_at(vars(ends_with("T")),  ~ ymd(.x, truncated = 2))
   city  name       hbpT        tbT      hepaT
1 CityA Angel 2011-10-01       <NA> 2009-09-09
2 CityA   Bob 2014-02-12 2009-09-09 2011-12-07
3 CityB Cathy 2011-10-12 2011-12-07       <NA>
4 CityB  Dean       <NA>       <NA> 2018-07-23
5 CityC Ellen 1992-10-01 2018-07-23       <NA>
6 CityC  Faye 2011-12-07       <NA>       <NA>
```

#### data

```
dirtydataset <- structure(list(city = c("CityA", "CityA", "CityB", 
"CityB", "CityC", 
"CityC"), name = c("Angel", "Bob", "Cathy", "Dean", "Ellen", 
"Faye"), hbpT = c("2011-101", "2014-02-12", "2011-10-12", NA, 
"1992.10.1", "2011-127"), tbT = c(NA, "20090909", "2011-127", 
NA, "2018.07.23", NA), hepaT = c("20090909", "2011-127", NA, 
"2018.07.23", NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative we could use `parse_date` function from `parsedate` package. Data from @r2evans (Many thanks).

`parse_date` can parse a date when you don’t know which format it is in. First it tries all ISO 8601 formats. Then it tries git’s versatile date parser. Lastly, it tries as.POSIXct.

```
library(dplyr)
library(parsedate)

dirtydataset %>% 
  mutate(across(ends_with("T"), ~parsedate::parse_date(.)))
```

output:

```
   city  name       hbpT        tbT      hepaT
1 CityA Angel 2011-04-11       <NA> 2009-09-09
2 CityA   Bob 2014-02-12 2009-09-09 2011-05-07
3 CityB Cathy 2011-10-12 2011-05-07       <NA>
4 CityB  Dean       <NA>       <NA> 2018-07-23
5 CityC Ellen 1992-10-01 2018-07-23       <NA>
6 CityC  Faye 2011-05-07       <NA>       <NA>
```